How to compare a value to a single filter date value in AWS Quicksight
I’m new to quicksight so apologize if the question is basic but I couldn’t find an answer in the other posts.
I have a field called submit and date range filter called startTime. What I’m looking to create is a calculated field that counts the number of submit values with the dateCreated (another date field from another dataSource) that falls within the range the user selects for startTime.
enter image description here
I was thinking of doing a countIf and pass the startTime and dateCreated values in it but I can’t figure out how to use a function for “FallsWithinThisDateRange” for a single filter like startTime.
So basically, countIf(clientDate is in the same range as startTime)
